# How to find transformation matrix from the output with Gaussian noise?

Tags: matlab, noise, noise-reduction, transformation-matrix

For the below given input and output, the matrix `A` can be found out by pseudoinverse or `mrdivision` in MATLAB.  Similarly, I would now like to know, how to determine `A`, if my output signal `Y` matrix contains additive zero mean, uncorrelated, Gaussian noise?

```
x1 = [1 1 1]';
x2 = [0 1 1]';
x3 = [0 0 1]';
x4 = [1 0 1]';

y1 = [1 2 0]';
y2 = [-1 0 3]';
y3 = [3 1 1]';
y4 = [5 3 -2]';

X = [x1 x2 x3 x4];
Y = [y1 y2 y3 y4];

A = Y/X
```

Also, I have modelled the unknown noisy output as below:

```
y1_n = y1 + sqrt(var(y1))*randn(size(y1));
y2_n = y2 + sqrt(var(y2))*randn(size(y2));
y3_n = y3 + sqrt(var(y3))*randn(size(y3));
y4_n = y4 + sqrt(var(y4))*randn(size(y4));
Y = [y1_n y2_n y3_n y4_n];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement `A = Y/X` solves the linear system of equations `A*X = Y`. If the system is overdetermined, as in your case, the solution given is the least squares solution. Thus, if you have additive, zero mean, uncorrelated, Gaussian noise on `Y`, then `A = Y/X` will give you the best possible, unbiased, estimate of `A`.

Note that the noise you add to your `Y` matrix is quite large, hence the estimate of `A` is far away from the ideal. If you add less noise, the estimate will be closer:

```matlab
x1 = [1 1 1]';
x2 = [0 1 1]';
x3 = [0 0 1]';
x4 = [1 0 1]';
X = [x1 x2 x3 x4];

y1 = [1 2 0]';
y2 = [-1 0 3]';
y3 = [3 1 1]';
y4 = [5 3 -2]';
Y = [y1 y2 y3 y4];

for n = [1,0.1,0.01,0]
   Y_n = Y + n*randn(size(Y));
   A = Y_n/X;
   fprintf('n = %f, A = \n',n)
   disp(A)
end
```

Output:

```
n = 1.000000, A = 
    2.9728   -5.5407    2.8011
    2.6563   -1.3166    0.6596
   -3.3366    1.1349    1.5342

n = 0.100000, A = 
    2.0011   -4.0256    2.9402
    1.9223   -1.0029    1.0921
   -3.1383    1.9874    1.0913

n = 0.010000, A = 
    1.9903   -3.9912    2.9987
    1.9941   -1.0001    1.0108
   -3.0015    2.0001    1.0032

n = 0.000000, A = 
    2.0000   -4.0000    3.0000
    2.0000   -1.0000    1.0000
   -3.0000    2.0000    1.0000
```

Of course if you make `X` and `Y` larger by adding more vectors you'll get a better estimate too, and will be able to compensate more noisy data.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I get that. But is there a way to filter the noise in Y and then do the pseudo inverse step. I am looking for a situation where my noise is unknown, but additive zero mean, uncorrelated, Gaussian. The variance, n = 1,0.1,0.01,0, is not desired but.

Comment: @Neuling: noise being noise, we cannot just remove it. Noise is a problem because it obscures data. If we could simply remove the noise, then noise wouldn't be a problem. If your `y1` vectors have a specific structure, you might be able to use that to reduce the noise. For example, if `y1` is a signal with temporal coherence, you can apply some temporal filtering that smooths the signal, improving the signal to noise ratio. But your question doesn't contain any information at all about these vectors, so we cannot do anything to get around the noise except use the least squares solution.